# Subtract two arrays in PHP using Raspberry

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, substr, subtraction

I have two arrays that each contains one mysql select from different days (24h interval). Arrays contains 1440 entries with another `sub-array(temp1, temp2, temp3 and date)`. I tried `foreach($array as $key=>$val)` but I can't subtract `$val` with or from another, let's say, `$val2`. The most legit way to do this is (based on web search):

```
foreach($yesterdayValues as $key=>$val){
    if(substr($key, 0, 5) == 'temp2')
        $todayValues[$key] -= $val;  
}
```

But it does not work.

The main idea is to subtract `temp2` values from today with the same `temp2` values from yesterday in order to see changes in temperature. And display them nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this (but it's kind of static for the moment):

```
for($i=0;$i<1440;$i++){
    (float)$yesterdayValues[$i]['temp2'] = (float)$last24hourValues[$i]['temp2'] - (float)$yesterdayValues[$i]['temp2'];
}
```

There are 1440 entries in 24h, and the key cand be acessed manually in a simple for. Maybe this can work with foreach instead of simple for. I will check later.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : Something like that ?

```
$yesterdayValues['temp1'] = 18.145666122437;
$yesterdayValues['temp2'] = 19.1425666122437;
$yesterdayValues['temp3'] = 20.845666122437;

$difference = array();
$i = 2;
foreach($yesterdayValues as $key=>$val){
    if(isset($yesterdayValues['temp'.$i])) {
        $difference[$key] = (float)($val - $yesterdayValues['temp'.$i]);
    }
    $i++;
}


var_dump($difference);
```

show : array(2) { ["temp1"]=> float(-0.9969004898067) ["temp2"]=> float(-1.7030995101933) }

Comment: var_dump($yesterdayValues) gives this:

array(1440) {
    [0]=> array(4) {
        ["temp1"]=> float(18.145666122437)
        ["temp2"]=> float(14.875) 
        ["temp3"]=> float(18.104000091553)
        ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-02-29 10:47:10" 
} 
    [1]=> array(4) { 
        ["temp1... 
and so on

Comment: No, there are two separate arrays, todayValues[] and yesterdayvalues[] with identical structure but different contents. And each temp2 from today minus each temp2 from yesterday will be our result. And if i subtract like that in the foreach loop it wont work. I tried this yesterday...

Answer (score 0):

may this work for you

```
$yesterdayValues = array(
    array('temp1'=>18.145666122437,'temp2'=>14.875, 'temp3'=>18.104000091553, 'date'=>'2016-02-29 10:47:10'),
    array('temp1'=>19.245666022437,'temp2'=>14.875, 'temp3'=>19.104000091553, 'date'=>'2016-02-29 11:47:10'),
    array('temp1'=>20.145666122437,'temp2'=>14.875, 'temp3'=>20.104000091553, 'date'=>'2016-02-29 12:47:10'),
) ;
$todaysValues = array(
    array('temp1'=>18.145666122437,'temp2'=>12.875, 'temp3'=>18.104000091553, 'date'=>'2016-02-29 10:47:10'),
    array('temp1'=>19.145666122437,'temp2'=>14.075, 'temp3'=>19.104000091553, 'date'=>'2016-02-29 11:47:10'),
    array('temp1'=>20.145666122437,'temp2'=>17.175, 'temp3'=>20.104000091553, 'date'=>'2016-02-29 12:47:10'),
) ;
$diffArr = array();
foreach ($yesterdayValues AS $key => $dataArr) {
    $diffArr[$key] = (float)($dataArr['temp2'] - $todaysValues[$key]['temp2']);
}
```

Comment: Nope, this does not work. I have to remind you that these were the forst choices, and the code is running on a Raspberry Pi. I guess it has something to do with PHP version.